# Python - tkinter - _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-comnmand"

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and all and I'm following a tutorial and all to get my head around how the functions work. I am using the exact same code as from the tutorial yet I still get this error - "_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-comnmand""

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tkinter as tk  # Import the module


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', comnmand=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()

app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample App')
app.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know of a solution or what I've done wrong? I've looked everywhere...

Comment: `comnmand`?  Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: comnmand should be command

Comment: You should believe error messages as they are correct at least 90% of the time.  Code runs fine with the misspelling corrected.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. Trust that the error message is telling you the literal truth.

Answer (score 3):

This should instead read

```
self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
```

and not

```
 self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', comnmand=self.quit)
```